# Rotation in an AVL Tree

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

While performing a rotation in an unbalanced binary search tree, we need to rotate the parent node[single rotation] if the imbalance is being caused in right-right or left-left. so the parent node can be easily accessed as it is being passed to the function.

```
 void add_node(T data,Node<T>* &node){
   if(this->root==nullptr){
     Node<T>* new_node= new Node<T>(data);
     this->root=new_node;
     
   }
   else{
     if(data<node->m_data){
       if(node->m_left!=nullptr){
         add_node(data,node->m_left);
     
       }else{
          
          Node<T>* new_node= new Node<T>(data);
          node->m_left=new_node;
          rebalance(node);
       }
     }
     if(data>node->m_data){
       if(node->m_right!=nullptr){
        add_node(data,node->m_right);
        
       }else{
          Node<T>* new_node= new Node<T>(data);
          node->m_right=new_node;
          
          rebalance(node);
       }
       
     }
   }
 }
```

But how do we access the ancestor node if we need to perform an LR or RL rotation?

```
 //BalanceFactor of a node
          int balance_factor(Node<T>* node){
          return height(node->m_left)-height(node->m_right);
      }
    Node<T>* rebalance(Node<T>* &node){
          int bal_fact=balance_factor(node);
           if(bal_fact>1){
               if(balance_factor(node->m_left)>0){
                 node=ll_rotate(node);
               }else{
                 node=lr_rotate(node);
               }
           }
           if(bal_fact<-1){
              if(balance_factor(node->m_right)>0){
                 node=rl_rotate(node);
               }else{
                 node=rr_rotate(node);
               }
           }
           return node;
         }
```

Comment: Why the need for ancestor node? The rebalancing occurs at the first node which is imbalanced and at most you would require it's parent's access. Ancestor node doesn't come into the picture.

Comment: I guess in case of LR and RL rotations we first rotate the parent and then the ancestor!

Comment: @srt1104 Anyways do you have some implementation?

Comment: You're looking at it wrong. See, when you talk of rotating at a node, that's because there is imbalance there. So if you're talking about rotating a parent and the grandparent, that's because there is an imbalance at the child. Balance the child and it's parent and grandparent get balanced automatically. To balance the child, you need just it's children. So rather than calling it the "child", let's call it the first node where imbalance occurs. I'll post my implementation in the answer.

Comment: @srt1104 Yeah please implementation would make it clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now there are multiple ways in which you could implement this; by passing the parent node, or by passing the left/right pointer of the parent by reference when you take left/right path respectively or by returning the root of the current subtree (after balancing if it's required) to the parent as you're moving up the tree.

I'll post the third way because it reduces code size.

```
int getHeight(Node *current) { return current == nullptr ? -1 : current->height; }
int getBalanceFactor(Node *current) { return getHeight(current->left) - getHeight(current->right); }

Node* rightRotate(Node *y)
{
    Node *x = y->left;

    y->left = x->right;
    x->right = y;

    y->height = max(getHeight(y->left), getHeight(y->right)) + 1;
    x->height = max(getHeight(x->left), getHeight(x->right)) + 1;

    return x;
}

Node* leftRotate(Node *x)
{
    Node *y = x->right;

    x->right = y->left;
    y->left = x;

    x->height = max(getHeight(x->left), getHeight(x->right)) + 1;
    y->height = max(getHeight(y->left), getHeight(y->right)) + 1;

    return y;
}

Node* insert(Node *current, int key)
{
    if (current == nullptr)
        return new Node(key);

    if (key <= current->key)
        current->left = insert(current->left, key);
    else
        current->right = insert(current->right, key);

    // the code hereonwards is when the control is returning from the stack, i.e., we are "moving" up the tree essentially
    current->height = max(getHeight(current->left), getHeight(current->right)) + 1;

    int bf = getBalanceFactor(current);
    // there's no imbalance, return the rooted subtree at `current` as it is
    if (-1 <= bf && bf <= 1)
        return current;

    if (bf == 2)
    {
        int bf_left = getBalanceFactor(current->left);

        // LL case
        if (bf_left == 1)
            return rightRotate(current);
        // LR case
        else
        {
            current->left = leftRotate(current->left);
            return rightRotate(current);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        int bf_right = getBalanceFactor(current->right);

        // RR case
        if (bf_right == -1)
            return leftRotate(current);
        // RL case
        else
        {
            current->right = rightRotate(current->right);
            return leftRotate(current);
        }
    }
}
```

And it should be called like `root = insert(root, key)`

Comment: current will be the node that we have inserted??

Comment: I meant after insertion !

Comment: As I said in the comment in code, after the node is inserted, we are essentially moving up the tree taking the exact same path we took which we came down to insert the new node. The `current` are the nodes on this path and we check if any of these are imbalanced.

Comment: Can you please tell me how are we moving up?? it's very confusing !

Comment: `insert` will keep calling itself until it reaches the base case, which is when `current == nullptr`. Once there, we create the new node and return it to the previous call of `insert`. Once there, suppose we had called it like `current->left = insert(current->left, key)`, the newly created node will get assigned to `current->left`. And then we check for imbalance. If there is need for balance, we rotate and return the root of this balanced subtree to the previous call of `insert` which will again assign this node to it's `current->left` or `current->right` depending on how it was called.

Answer (score 0):

You either must have the parent as part of the node data structure (my personal preference as it allows for easy determination of the next and prior in-order nodes) and you can retrieve the parent's parent or you must keep track of each parent and grandparent as you go down the tree looking for the insertion location.

If using the latter method if you don't have a parent then you know the current node is the tree root, if you have a parent but don't have a grandparent you know the parent is the tree root.